# How to show string in xml format in erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the controller, I have an variable `@xml_string = "<tag> hello \n world </tag>"`. Now I want to show the content of `@xml_string`. In erb file I wrote `<%= @xml_string %>`, but this can only display `hello world`, the xml tag `<tag>  </tag>` was missed and `\n` was ignored.

Aslo , `<% render :text => @xml_string , :content_type = 'application/xml' %>` would not show any thing at all.

what is the correct way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML ignores new line characters and white spaces unless you wrap the content into a tag that is whitespace-aware.

```
<pre><%=h @xml_string %></pre>
```

Otherwise, replace the "\n" with a line break. In this case you need to manually escape the HTML string.

```
<%=h @xml_string.gsub("<", "&lt;").gsub("\n", "<br>") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<%=h @xml_string %>
```

Comment: @khell, now I can show `<tag>` but `\n` was still ignored. +1

Comment: change the double quotes to single quotes when assigning the string to the @xml_string var

Comment: Actually, the content was read from xml file using `File.open("a.xml").read`. What should I do in this case?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
<%=h @xml_string.dump[1..-2] %>
```

The `dump` method will simply return the string in a way that makes `str == eval(str.dump)`. That means it includes the quotes, so you need the `[1..-2]` to slice those away.